# SQLite - Get Winner of Each Game (Rank Over Partition )

Tags: sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, rank, partition

I'm creating a score tracking app for Carcassonne. I'd like to get the Winner of each game.

I've got this working in MS-SQL and now I'm trying to convert the db to SQLite.

**Schema**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e8340

MS-SQL

```
CREATE VIEW vTopScorePerGame AS
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [GameID] ORDER BY TotalScore DESC) AS Position,
                   PlayerID,
                PlayerName, 
                TotalScore,
                [GameID]
    FROM        vScore
)
SELECT      [GameID],
            PlayerID,
            PlayerName AS Winner,
            TotalScore
FROM        ranked      
WHERE       ranked.Position = 1
```

When I'm trying in SQLFiddle or SQLiteBrowser I'm getting the following error:

```
near "(": syntax error:
```

Can someone point me  in the right direction?

---

*Functions*
WITH
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html
COALESCE
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

*Unsupported*
http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions

Comment: Have you used a CTE within SQLite before? One thing you might try is defining the CTE with column names before `AS`. I know in SQL Server you don't have to, but maybe SQLite requires it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can simply use MAX() to get values from the the row with the largest value in the group:

```
SELECT GameID,
       PlayerID,
       PlayerName AS Winner,
       MAX(TotalScore) AS TotalScore
FROM vScore
GROUP BY GameID;
```

In earlier versions, you can get the players with the larget score in a separate subquery, and then join them with the original table:

```
SELECT GameID,
       PlayerID,
       PlayerName AS Winner,
       TotalScore
FROM vScore
JOIN (SELECT GameID,
             (SELECT PlayerID
              FROM vScore AS s2
              WHERE s2.GameID = GameIDs.GameID
              ORDER BY TotalScore DESC
              LIMIT 1
             ) AS PlayerID
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GameID
            FROM vScore) AS GameIDs)
     USING (GameID, PlayerID);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems much simpler.